# Building a graph from ordered pairs

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have some code which generates an array; at each index there is an array with an x and y coordinate. I wanted to plot the points as a graph using d3.js, but am not sure how to go about that.

I have looked at the site and the examples but have found nothing that would help me with this task. This [link here](http://socr.ucla.edu/htmls/HTML5/charts/SOCR_JS_ViolinChart/) is an example of the type of graph I am trying to create, except I want to be able to create multiple graphs on one grid.

I basically need some guidance on how to get started, because I am completely lost. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a bit too general for StackOverflow - most SO questions show some code you've already tried. Most likely the d3 mailing list is a better fit for the "How do I get started?" style of question.

Comment: basically, i am trying to figure out how to how to draw a curve given the ordered pairs. Thats what I need help figuring out. If its to basic, please redirect me to where I could get help with this.

Comment: Please post a sample of your data points instead of just describing them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might better be a comment but I don't have comment access.  First of all what is the name of the type of graph you link to in your question?  It's not your basic pie or bar graph.

If you want multiple sets of data on one graph, what type of graph do you want?  I can't visualize what you are trying to do so I don't know how best to help.  Here is a good [list of tutorials](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials) that link out to examples of how to use D3.

Comment: basically, i am trying to figure out how to how to draw a curve given the ordered pairs. Thats what I need help figuring out. If its to basic, please redirect me to where I could get help with this. I have generated the array with the ordered pairs for the curve (similar to the outline of the plot that I linked to) and I just need some help creating a curve with the data. I think I should be able to get it going from there.

Comment: Sorry, im kinda new here. still getting used to how it works =)